# How can I make my younger brother's interest in physics at home?

Tags: soft-question, education

This is a soft question. I have a younger brother who is in 10th standard but he don't like subject of physics at all. When I asked reason for it he says he gets bored in mugging the formulas of physics theorem that are taught in his school. He don't like theortical explaination but when I explain it with any practical example,he understand it clearly.

For example, to  show that light is made of different colors, I put prism .When light is passed through it , the white light gets spit into different colors.

It's like image is equal to thousand words.

So can anyone suggest any experiment (not of any perticular theorem ) that can be possible to carry out at home or ourselves to make interest and increase interest in physics and physical phenomena so that children find it simple to study subject of physics ?

Comment: http://coolscienceclub.tripod.com/id6.html

Comment: Veritasium? aka element 42.0, probably the first hit on Google. I guess it focuses on misconceptions, but often that's the interesting part: "what you know ain't so."

Comment: "What can I show my brother to get him interested in physics?" seems very broad (too many possible answers)

Comment: @pentane yes I agree that there could be many possible answers but this is soft question and if you check other stackexchange sites ,there have allowed such questions as soft question. Also, is it necessary that every question on this site should have particular solution(/s)?

Comment: Our stance here is that yes, all questions should have objective answers. Moreover our scope is just physics, not the teaching or culture around physics. (Unfortunately there exist some relic tags from many years ago before the site had established its identity.) I can't make any guarantees, but you might try [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/) for suggestions on developing children's interest in science.

Comment: @Chris White I really don't understand why people here behave like short minded . If you see other stackexchange sites like mathstackexchange ,there are many similar questions with huge reputation like [question1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain), [question 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/what-was-the-first-bit-of-mathematics-that-made-you-realize-that-math-is-beautif) ,[question 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416226/my-sister-absolutely-refuses-to-learn-math) and many more

Comment: In short: you can't. He has to develop a taste for it on his own.

Comment: The users of [physics.se] have voted more than one to *not* be like [math.se] in terms of accommodating homeworkesque and make-a-list questions. We don't want highly voted lists of cool stuff. We want a catalog of good physics questions with good answers.

Answer (score 5):

10th grade is 15/16 years old right? Even if i'm more for a theoretical approach I think that age should be the age of experiments. He clearly doesn't have the mathematical background to do "real" theoretical physics. They just probably try to shove formulas into his head without explanations. I advice you to keep going with these kind of experiments, maybe if you have time you can make them more quantitative in order to have an application of those formulas. You can show him conservation of momentum with some balls, you can show him conservation of angular momentum just with a rotating bar and some weights on it (you move the weights during rotation so the moment of inertia changes and consequently the angular velocity). Mechanics is probably the most boring field from an experimental point of view. If you get him interested in fluid dynamics or electromagnetism you could have way more fun I think. And as regards fluid dynamics, if his math is not good enough he's just like the best mathematicians and physicist in the world (Navier-Stokes equation).

About the theoretical part, I think you should make him appreciate the beauty of the formulas, trying to explain them to him, to make him guess what happens if you modify a physical quantity. Then do an experiment to see if he guessed right. In this way he'll learn he can make predictions out of formulas. Try to explain how fantastic those formulas are and where they come from, how they are not so banal. Like ${\bf{F}}=m\bf{a}$ is not an equation, it's not something to solve. It's the most basic principle of the whole classical mechanics. It relates 3 different quantities which may exist independently from the other ones, but nature put a restriction on them.

To conclude. If it's just a teaching problem he may be (like the majority of the people in my opinion) inclined to physics without knowing it. You gotta consider the fact that he may be totally disinterested in it, in this case, forcing him to learn all that stuff my not be right in my opinion.

Comment: He's 15/16? Find some cute girls who think physics is cool.

Comment: I agree with pretty much all of what you said, but I know a large number of very smart people in the biotech industry, all of whom are PhDs in chemistry, biochemistry, have a medical degree etc. and they are all running when they are hearing the word "physics". It's not that these people don't have the right intellectual qualities, they most certainly do and they can deal with systems that are, on average, far more complex than the ones we are dealing with, but there is something structural about the way physicists think (reductionism) that makes many even highly educated people uncomfortable.

Comment: @CuriousOne I gotta agree with you. But those are already formed minds. In my opinion almost every kid has a basic inclination to physics, a very intuitive and experimental kind of inclination. Then I agree on the fact that when it comes to actually study it and formalize it it may be unpleasant for most of the people. But I think the inclination is there. About reductionism, excluding math from sciences physics is the most reductionist one, and that is it's force. Exam of electromagnetism: at the end of the day you learn 4 formulas to explain an incredibly HUGE variety of natural phenomena.

Comment: Chemistry exam: Learn a lot of unsignificant(from a physical point of view) rules with no general validity, which apply just in some cases, to solve a special case. Other cases other rules. I admire who does that, and I like to know the informations chemistry, like other science give us, i just don't get how a mind can like those or prefer them to physics. Maybe it's this lack of understanding other kind of minds that makes me think almost everybody probably have an inclination to physics.

Comment: I wish I could put my finger on what it is that causes so much frustration for many with physics. I know that there are components in the way we teach it that are problematic, but they are problematic for students and physics teachers, alike. My high school teacher told me that he knew from experience that teaching Newton with force gauges leads to kids identifying forces with spring elongation, rather than acceleration of test masses. He had a number of these "pitfalls" for the average student and he was very unhappy that he didn't manage to work around them.

Comment: As for chemistry: I talked to a chemistry student once and she made it sufficiently clear to me that I had just as many misconceptions about chemistry as she had about physics. That was after her second attempt to pass a one month long exam consisting of exactly one synthesis starting with gallons of material to end up with milligrams of the final product... that had to meet both purity and efficiency requirements. Any science, when done professionally, is a different animal from what the outsider sees. Chemistry, for sure, is as quantitative as we are, we just don't get to see it.

Comment: It is not as general as physics is, they have to learn way more things to explain way less phenomena. It's intrinsic in the nature of that science since we can't solve Schrodinger equation in almost any case. They have to make up rules and things to figure it out, it's the only way. Consequently the amount of concept and ideas they have to learn is way bigger compared to what we have to learn, since they not have and ${\bf{F}}=m\bf{a}$ which the answer to anything for us basically. Not the answer, but you can always go back to it from almost anything in classical physics.

Comment: As far as regards real teaching to a group of people I think i'm not qualified to even express an opinion. Teaching is school is way too different from one on one teaching (what I only did in my life) and too many things beside the physics and how you teach it have to be considered. Too many social and group dynamics that clearly don't fit my assumption of one spherical person  which emit as perfect blackbody, and since it is a perfect emitter is a perfect absorber (of information) too!

Answer (score 3):

Tell him how to build an atomic bomb. Kids loves it.

In principle:

1. Start with a shocking and dangerous idea.
2. Show him an exciting experiment and explain this.
3. Make him do something what requires new knowledge.

For example:
Tell him about space exploration, that he can do it by himself,
build a model rocket with him,
Teach him the Newtonian dynamics and let him improve his rocket basing on his new knowledge.